# Как запустить функцию в определенное время в дни недели?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, schedule

Нужно запускать функцию, например, каждый понедельник, в определенный час и минуту. Пробовал через `shedule`, но он запросто не хочет работать, да и проблемы с днями недели возникли... Вот мой код:

```py
# Импорт модулей
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
import schedule
import time


# Вывод сообщений
def send_message(peer_id, message):
    vk.messages.send(
        peer_id=peer_id,
        message=message,
        random_id=get_random_id(),
    )

# Функция вызова
def prizyv():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id=2000000013,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Призыв!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000013, message)

# Функция вызова по утрам
def prizyv_morning():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id=2000000013,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Доброе утро! Хочу напомнить вам что сегодня вебинар. Всем хорошего дня'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000013, message)

# Функция вызова за час
def prizyv_hour():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id=2000000013,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Всем привет! Хочу напомнить что через час у вас вебинар. За 10 минут до начала вебинара я скину вам ссылку.'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000013, message)

# Функция вызова за 10 минут
def prizyv_10minute():
    members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(
        peer_id=2000000013,
    )['items']

    members_ids = [member['member_id'] for member in members if member['member_id'] > 0]

    message = 'Итак, ровно через 10 минут начинается вебинар! Вот вам ссылка: *Тут ссылка*. Всем удачи!!!!!'
    for member_id in members_ids:
        message += f'[id{member_id}|#]'

    send_message(2000000013, message)


accessToken = 'removed for security reasons' 
groupId = 123456789  # removed for security reasons

vkBotSession = VkApi(token=accessToken)
longPoll = VkBotLongPoll(vkBotSession, groupId)
vk = vkBotSession.get_api()


for event in longPoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        from_id = event.obj['from_id']  
        peer_id = event.obj['peer_id']  
        message = event.obj['text'].lower()
        if ('крут' in message) and message != 'полностью согласен! реально круто ':
            send_message(peer_id, 'О да, это точно круто! B-)')
        elif message == 'призыв!' and from_id == 504785497:
            prizyv()


schedule.every().day.at("01:50").do(prizyv_10minute) # это не работает, возможно я не так делаю
```

PS Бот будет стоять на `pythonanywhere`

Comment: Естественно, не работает, последняя строка будет выполнена только тогда, когда завершится предыдущий цикл, а он завершается с прекращением работы бота.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цикл `longPoll.listen()` является бесконечным. Последняя строка никогда не выполнится.

Но просто запустить задачи до цикла тоже не получится, потому что через определённое время их нужно проверять, а `longPoll.listen()` может спать довольно долго.

Я предлагаю Вам запустить цикл проверки задач (вместе с их объявлениями) в отдельном потоке, используя модуль `threading`.

---

Для этого создайте функцию, в которой будет находиться бесконечный цикл проверки задач и их объявления (опционально). Примерно так:

```
def scheduler():
    schedule.every(5).seconds.do(send_message, 2000000013, 'Test message')

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(1)  # Выберите оптимальное значение под свои задачи планировщика
```

И запустите её в отдельном потоке (естественно, до бесконечного цикла), чтобы она не зависела от `longPoll.listen()` (который может очень долго спать) и не мешала его же быстродействию:

```py
t = Thread(target=scheduler)
t.start()
```

Данный небольшой пример каждые 5 секунд будет вызывать функцию `send_message(2000000013, 'Test message')`.

---

***Пример:***

```
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
import schedule
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


def send_message(peer_id, message):
    vk.messages.send(
        peer_id=peer_id,
        message=message,
        random_id=get_random_id(),
    )


def scheduler():
    schedule.every(5).seconds.do(send_message, 2000000013, 'Test message')

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(1)  # Выберите оптимальное значение под свои задачи планировщика


accessToken = 'removed for security reasons'
groupId = 'removed for security reasons'

vkBotSession = VkApi(token=accessToken)
longPoll = VkBotLongPoll(vkBotSession, groupId)
vk = vkBotSession.get_api()

# Создаём и запускаем планировщик в отдельном потоке
t = Thread(target=scheduler)
t.start()

# Бесконечный цикл
for event in longPoll.listen():
    pass
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает.